# How to export list values to CSV file in one row..?

Tags: python, loops, csv, flask, iteration

I have a **list** like this:

```
name_CL =  ['Lolo', 'Fadli', 'Jori', 'Andi', 'Budi', 'Dedi', 'Nori']
```

and i want to export the list to a CSV file using **Flask-CSV** using this code :

```
name_CL_to_CSV = []

for i in name_CL:
    name_CL_to_CSV.append(i)
return send_csv([{'Name CL' : name_CL_to_CSV}],
        "testing.csv", ['Name CL'])
```

But the result is like this

[image]

and then a try to modify the code a little bit like this:

```
name_CL_to_CSV = []

for i in name_CL:
    name_CL_to_CSV.append(i)
    return send_csv([{'Name CL' : name_CL_to_CSV}],
            "testing.csv", ['Name CL'])
```

just modify the indentation in **for loop**.

and then i got this result:

[image]

So.. my question is how to get all of values in that list in one row on CSV file..?

What i want is the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Try using tuples instead of lists

Comment: still got the same result @m33n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
name_CL_to_CSV = []

for i in name_CL:
    name_CL_to_CSV.append({'Name CL' : i})
return send_csv(name_CL_to_CSV,
        "testing.csv", ['Name CL'])
```

Comment: i got this error @Dithon:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`,
i think it must be a dictionary.

Comment: ah.. sorry @Dithon and  Geeocode, i didn't scrupulous, it's works fine now, thanks :)